# set background colour in tables based on merge field from serial letter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, merge

I have set up a  word document as a serial letter containing a table referencing data from an excel document.
The table in the word document should change the cells background colour if another field has a certain value (e.g. "cold" -> background colour in the table should be blue).

I have tried using an If statement with mergefield, but i can only change the formatting of the string, but not the background of the cell. Below is the code i tried:

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD Temperature = "cold" "Store at 8°C" "Store at RT" }                                |
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Borders and Shading control on the Home tab, you can *shade* the truetext and false text in your [IF Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#IF_field). This will not change the background of the cell, but it will of the text.

You have asked about using Case or Else. There is no Case field structure. The simplest method is multiple IF fields. You can also nest IF Fields by placing additional IF Fields as the truetext or falsetext. Normally it is as the falsetext. Here is an example of a nested field.

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD Temperature = "cold" "Store at 8°C" { IF { MERGEFIELD Temperature = "hot" "Store at 30°C" "Store at RT" } }
```

Lengthy or complex fields are best written outside of a table structure and then copied into the table cell.

*(Link about IF field is to my web page on fields in Word.)*

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to use "case" or "else" statemens? I likely will encounter more than 2 cases,

Comment: Thanks! greatly appreciated!